# React Infinite Scrolling with Search functionality

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I implemented infinite scrolling to my MERN app it works ok ,In addition to that I can also search specific item (instantly). If items match with search area text it automatically get data from server and display it on screen and i can paginate these search results also BUT when i clean search input area i can not use pagination function because "page" number (useState) automatically increased in the previous step. How can I handle this problem?

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const getData = async () => {
      const { data } = await axios(
        search
          ? `http://localhost:3003/api/product/pagination?page=0&search=${search}`
          : `http://localhost:3003/api/product/pagination?page=0`
      );

      setData(data.posts);
    };

    if (search.length === 0 || search.length > 2) {
      getData();
    }
  }, [search]);

  const fetchPosts = async () => {
    const { data } = await axios(
      `http://localhost:3003/api/product/pagination?page=${page}&search=${search}`
    );

    return data.posts;
  };

  const fetchData = async () => {
    const postsFromServer = await fetchPosts();
    setData([...data, ...postsFromServer]);

    if (postsFromServer.length === 0 || postsFromServer.length < 4) {
      setHasMore(false);
    }
    setPage(page + 1);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <InfiniteScroll
        dataLength={data.length} //This is important field to render the next data
        next={fetchData}
        hasMore={hasMore}
        loader={<h4>Loading...</h4>}
      >
        <Container>
            .map((item) => {
              const {
                _id,
                kampaniyaName,
                owner,
                aboutProduct,
                startDate,
                endDate,
                price,
                category,
                image,
              } = item;

              return (
                <div key={item._id}>
                  <Card
                    _id={_id}
                    name={kampaniyaName}
                    company={owner}
                    about={aboutProduct}
                    date={timeLeft(startDate, endDate)}
                    price={price}
                    category={category}
                    image={image}
                    data={item}
                  />
                </div>
              );
            })}
        </Container>
      </InfiniteScroll>
    </>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

Comment: please generate minimum reproduction on stackblitz or codesandbox so easy to other dev to understand